# Multivariate distribution with specific (multivariate) marginal distributions

Tags: multivariate-analysis, marginal-distribution

Let suppose I have a 6-variate random variable $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$.

What I want is to define a multivariate distribution for $\mathbf{x}$ with some specific multivariate marginals. More precisely I'd like that the subsets  $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $(x_4,x_5,x_6)$, $(x_1,x_4)$, $(x_2,x_5)$, $(x_3,x_6)$ have some specific distributions. 
Is there some results that can help me in building a multivariate distribution with the desired properties?

Thank you

Comment: You can have a look at the theory of copulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory) . These are used to define multivariate distributions with specific marginals. In the standard formulation, the marginals are for each random variable separately and not for subsets of random variables as you want. But perhaps you could work it out.

Comment: Thank you. I already did it. And It seems that copulas cannot be used in this context.

Comment: It seems to me that copulas are the only possible way to approach this problem, unless these marginals have very special forms (such as Bernoulli or Normal).

Comment: The trivariate ones are Dirichlet.